# How should I initialise a shared-pointer member?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I can initialize a `std::shared_ptr` member in 2 different ways in my constructor (which both increment its `use_count`):

1. **Pass by reference**:

   ```
   class MyClass {
       std::shared_ptr<std::string> s1;
   public:
       MyClass(std::shared_ptr<std::string>& s2): s1{s2} {}
   };
   ```
2. **Pass by value**

   ```
   class MyClass2 {
       std::shared_ptr<std::string> s1;
   public:
       MyClass2(std::shared_ptr<std::string> s2): s1{std::move(s2)} {}
   };
   ```

---

Test program:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s2 = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello World");
    MyClass myClass {s2};
    MyClass2 myClass2 {s2};
    
    std::cout << "Use count:" << s2.use_count() << std::endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Use count:3
```

I don't see any advantage of the 2nd way over the 1st way.
I think the 2nd way should never be used because there is an extra move operation.

Which way do you think is better to initialise a `std::shared_ptr`, in terms of performance?

#### Updated

I can update `MyClass` according to below so it can be called like:
`MyClass myClass {std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello World")};`

```
class MyClass {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s1;
public:
    MyClass(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& s2): s1{s2} {}
};
```

Performance I guess makes a difference in too many loops.

#### Benchmark

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s1;
public:
    MyClass(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& s2): s1{s2} {}
};

class MyClass2 {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s1;
public:
    MyClass2(std::shared_ptr<std::string> s2): s1{std::move(s2)} {}
};


int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s2 = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello Wolrd");
    
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        MyClass myClass {s2};
    }    
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    std::chrono::duration<float> duration = end - start;
    std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;
    
    
    
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        MyClass2 myClass2 {s2};
    }    
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    duration = end - start;
    std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;    
        
    return 0;
}
```

Online c++ compiler and c++17

```
0.358915
0.623789
```

Comment: `I don't see any advantage of the 2nd way over the 1st way.` The second example allows  you to move into `s2`.

Comment: There's not an "extra" move operation. One has a copy operation, and one has a move operation. The move is just more letters to type, but is faster in general.

Comment: As a general rule, it's a code smell to be passing a shared_ptr as an lvalue ref (const or otherwise)

Comment: Your test program misses the advantage, which is apparent when you have `MyClass third{std::make_shared<std::string>("Goodbye world")};`, or when you no longer need `s2` in its scope, so use `MyClass fourth{std::move(s2)};`.

Comment: The problem is that you have the wrong idea about how `std::move` works (it does have a confusing name). It's not an operation that moves something. It's a type conversion that allows a move operation to occur. There is no cost to `std::move` and there is potentially a great saving.

Comment: Those test results are suspicious, because in your test, you're always copying the input, exactly once, so they should have had identical times. That test isn't taking advantage of the fact that `MyClass2` can be moved *into*.

Comment: In your tests, you're still not moving from the source, you're copying, so you won't see the benefits in that situation.

Answer (score 9):

The first way *requires* at least one copy of the `shared_ptr` (from `s2` to `s1`), regardless of what the calling function does, which requires grabbing locks, incrementing and decrementing the reference count, and other overhead.
Also, since the first version requires a `shared_ptr&`, then if the calling function has a temporary `shared_ptr&&`, then they're forced to store it in a variable before constructing the class:

```
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> s2 = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello World");
    MyClass myClass {s2};
```

The second way allows the caller to move a `shared_ptr` value into the constructor, which is then moved directly into `s1`. Move operations are cheaper: they do not require locks, and they do not increment or decrement the reference count. They're insanely fast.  Also, since the second one just takes a value, it can be constructed in any way, and therefore can be constructed directly from temporaries:

```
    MyClass myClass {std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello World")};
```

So the second way is superior in every way.

In my tests that mirror your tests, the `move` version is ~10% faster.
https://quick-bench.com/q/P3pX-bC8kRXSEmqJw2_KSz-kc0s

Comment: thanks for answer. i updated my question. maybe it makes a difference in too many loops.

Comment: @Metropol_Tilkisi: In my tests, the `move` version is ~10% faster, after excluding the work of allocating dynamic strings. https://quick-bench.com/q/P3pX-bC8kRXSEmqJw2_KSz-kc0s